# How to prepend text (not HTML) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

I realise that I can prepend stuff to an element using:

```
$(...).prepend(myText);
```

However, if `myText` is, let’s say, `"<span>"`, I actually want that text to appear, but `.prepend()` would instead prepend an empty span element. What is the recommended way to solve this? Do I really have to HTML-escape the text manually or is there something more elegant?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a textnode and put the contents there and `prepend` that:

```
$('div').prepend(document.createTextNode("<span>"));
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/gCKHe/

Comment: hi, this fiddle is not working in case when div has " <div> <script> alert('asfasfsfsfsfsffsafasf'); </script></div>"  html.
if you have any solution for that plz provide.
TIA :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `text` function instead of `prepend`, and simply add the original text to the end of the new text:

`$("#elementID").text("<span>" + $("#elementID").text());`

Comment: What if the *original element* contains html as well? It will all be **lost**.

Comment: Indeed... that's a good point! Your method is undoubtedly better.

Answer (score 1):

HTML entities are ok, in my opinion:

```
$(...).prepend('&lt;span&gt;');
```

You may automate the entities with the tip found at http://debuggable.com/posts/encode-html-entities-with-jquery:480f4dd6-13cc-4ce9-8071-4710cbdd56cb

```
$(...).prepend($('<div/>').text('<span>').html());
```

If you also want to create PHP's function **htmlentities** in Javascript, you may use the code available at PHP-JS project: http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425

Or you may simplify by wrapping the previous tip in a function:

```
function htmlentities(string) {
  return $('<div/>').text(string).html();
}
```

In both cases, you would use the htmlentities function like this:

```
$(...).prepend(htmlentities('<span>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement HTML encode (and decode) functions, like this accepted answer:   [HTML-encoding lost when attribute read from input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding)

and then do:

```
$(...).prepend(htmlEncode(myText));
```